# Debugging angular-ui bootstrap's typeahead exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

we are using angular-ui bootstrap (angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap), and more specifically the typeahead feature. This have been working fine but after an update from version 0.10 to 0.13 we are getting exceptions "Cannot read property '0' of null" and I'm struggling to find the cause of this exception but I have no idea on how to do that.

Currently I use the sample code from angular-ui's page (the first typeahead box with the US states). I assume that this exception is not really related to angular-ui it self, rather some code in our application. But I need help on finding where...

Can anyone shed some light on how ?

[image: Exception using typeahead]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the templates was newer than the js files.